# How to disprove grammar of being LL(3)?

Tags: parsing, grammar, automata, ll-grammar

I have the following grammar I made up:

```
S -> a a a t | a a a a
```

I'm trying to prove that it's not LL(3). I found that `First(S)={a}` and `Follow(S)={$}` but I can't seem to figure out what I need to do to disprove it being LL(3). It's a small grammar I built for myself to understand how to disprove LL(k). For LL(1) I build a table and in each field I insert the rule base on there First/Follow. But with lookahead 3 how can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

To prove a grammar is (not) LL(3), you need to construct an LL(3) parser for it and show that there is (or is not) a conflict in the resulting table.

To construct the parser tables for LL(3) you need FIRST<sub>3</sub> and FOLLOW<sub>3</sub>, which are analogous to FIRST and FOLLOW, except they are sets of sequences of (up to) 3 tokens, rather than sets of single tokens.  So you get FIRST<sub>3</sub>(S) = { "aaa" } which can select either production for S, giving you a conflict in the table between those productions.